# php unlink() function permission denied issue

Tags: php, permission-denied

file delete from database but not unlink from local folder warning appear: permission denied on file path

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$checkedCandidates = 0;
    $id = implode(",", $_POST['deletecb']);
    $checkedCandidates = count($id);
    $res=mysqli_query("SELECT file FROM video_gallery where id_vid IN($id) and users_name='$login_session'");
    mysqli_fetch_array($res);
     #chown(data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/videos, 777);
    // here "data/58f60f2e09f07_jay" is file path
    unlink("data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/$row[FILE_NAME]");
    $query1=mysqli_query($connection,"delete from video_gallery where id_vid IN($id) and users_name='$login_session'");

        if($query1)
        {
            echo "<div id=\"successmsg\"> delete successfully </div>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> failed operation!!</div>";
        }
}
}
```

Comment: please use the markup feature of the editor, this is not readable; also include what rights did you set in `videos` directory

Comment: unlink("path/$row[FILE_NAME]");

what is path? and use $row['FILE_NAME'];

Comment: path is file path i.e "data/58f60f2e09f07_jay"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give a write permission that folder. it will be 777. Give a permission that folder then try to unlink.

To unlink, the web server user must have write permissions to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

i think u work on your localhost
and your local host file path "data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/videos" permission issue
I think you need to give a write permission that folder